# Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow when sum

Tags: vb.net

I can't sum

```
Dim calc1 As Integer = 1391998071
Dim calc2 As Integer = 2020713278

Dim total As Integer = calc1 + calc2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Long](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/numeric-data-types#large-integers) datatype instead:

```vb
Dim calc1 As Long = 1391998071
Dim calc2 As Long = 2020713278
Dim totaa As Long = (calc1) + (calc2)
```